# Setting to allow silent renew with prompt=none

Tags: openid-connect, openiddict

Does OpenIddict support silent renew? How do we configure it?

I am current getting a 400 from this request:

> http://localhost:12345/connect/authorize?client_id=Aurelia.OpenIdConnect&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid%20email%20roles%20profile&state=9b394f7c978545a784a41f263f76677d&nonce=4ec03fedb16543ac98be37b540a1b73a&prompt=none

OpenIddict responds with this:

```
error: invalid_request
error_description: The required id_token_hint parameter is missing.
```

Some clients, such as oidc-client-js, do not include the hint. Is there a way to disable the hint requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to disable the hint requirement?

No. That said, it's a requirement I plan to relax in a future version.